# Big Query - And/Or Operators

Tags: selection, google-bigquery, operator-keyword

I try to get an answer database that gives me all data for Destination US and different origin countries. In one row however may be written CN,HK,JP - meaning numerous things. So, the Query I write is the following, but the answers contain only origin CN or HK but not "CN,JP,HK".
 What is the right code?

```
SELECT destination_country,origin_country, createDate FROM [DataWarehouse.Draft] 
Where destination_country contains "US"
And originCountries In ("CN", "HK")
```

Row originCountries destinationCountries    createWeek
1   CN  US  2014W30
2   CN  US  2014W30
3   CN  US  2014W30
4   CN  US  2014W30
5   HK  US  2014W30
6   HK  US  2014W30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an AND/OR question indeed.

Try:

```
SELECT destination_country,origin_country, createDate FROM [DataWarehouse.Draft] 
Where destination_country contains "US"
And (originCountries CONTAINS "CN" OR originCountries CONTAINS "HK")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `origin_country` data is currently flattened inside the `originCountries` field. You need to expand this (flattened) field into a repeated field. I don't know your exact schema, but something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT destination_country, SPLIT(originCountries, ",") as origin_country,
   createDate FROM [DataWarehouse.Draft])
WHERE destination_country contains "US" And origin_country IN ("CN", "HK")
```

should do what you need. I don't know if this version performs well or not, but it should do the filtering you want.

See the `SPLIT` documentation in the [string function reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#stringfunctions) documentation, and the documentation about [nested and repeated fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested).